# Scriptsteps counter in external function bash

Tags: bash, function, count

I have a script where I want to include output for better visibility (e.g "Step x from x).
I´d like to have an external function, that counts its own calls in the forementioned script to have a dynamic feedback depending on how many calls there are (so I can dynamically use it for other scripts as well.

The function stepcount() should read the script where it was called and grep all its own function calls (but only once when first called).
Then set a variable to the number of calls greped.
After that it should echo the increasing number of steps of the total number of steps (1 of x, 2 of x etc.) with a loop on every new function call without resetting the total number of steps from its first call.

Hopefully you guys can help me? Thanks a ton in advance!
I will put my tiny progress over the original code. I forfeited the loop as it was absolutly contraproductive

```
NEW
 function stepcount()  {
if [ -z "$MAXCOUNT" ]
  then
    echo "i get a value"
    MAXCOUNT="$(grep "stepcount" $0 | wc -l)"
    COUNTER=1
    echo "max count: $STEPCOUNT"
  else
    echo "i am not empty"
    COUNTER="$(echo "$COUNTER + 1" | bc)"
  fi

  echo "curr count: $COUNTER"
}

OLD
function stepcount()  {

        if [ -z "$MAXCOUNT" ] then
                $MAXCOUNT=$(grep "stepcount" $0 | wc -l)
                COUNTER=1
        else
               echo "not empty"
               COUNTER="$(echo "(($COUNTER +1))"
        fi

            echo -e "Step $COUNTER of $MAXCOUNT"
```

Comment: Your `grep` reads from standard input, and the stores the number of word in all lines from stdin which contain the substring _stepcount_ into MAXCOUNT. What's the point of this?

Comment: Hi, in the meantime I realised that I have to change this line to ```MAXCOUNT=$(grep "stepcount" $0 | wc -w)``` to grep the number of function calls from function "stepcount" in the script where the function will be called. The point ist to have a valid variable to declare the maximum number of stepf in the script. So everytime "stepcount" will be called, this script has the same number of steps as functioncalls

Comment: You don't get the number of function calls, but the number of words in this line. For instance, if the line says `stepcount ; do_work # This is a comment`, this already yields a total of 8 words.

Comment: Thanks, changed it to -l

Comment: This would give a wrong count if you had a line `stepcount; do_work; stepcount; do_more_work`

Comment: Please check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net before posting here. `$MAXCOUNT=` is invalid. `"$(echo "(($COUNTER +1))"` is invalid, either a useless use of echo and it doesn't increment the varibale, it outputs _the string_ `"((1+1))"`.

Comment: @user1934428 that doesn´t matter to me as the function is something I´m implementing in other scripts where I can determine the end of lines myself.

Comment: @KamilCuk You´re both right, I should have done that. Sorry for that, I was a overly hasty. I checked the code and made some corrections, now syntax should be alright and it outputs all the steps according to the number of functioncalls.